# Does polars support writing dataframe out of core, like `numpy.mmap`?

Tags: python, python-polars

I want to handle a large parquet dataset and write the data to one file. However, the dataset is too large to load them to memory at one time. So I want to load one file once and handle it, then write it to a file in the way of memory_map, just like `numpy.mmap` with setting `offset` and `mode='r+'`. Does polars support writing dataframe in this way ?

Comment: The new version **numpy 2** will be release on February 1st, 2024.

Comment: `.scan_parquet` + [`.sink_parquet`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/api/polars.LazyFrame.sink_parquet.html#polars.LazyFrame.sink_parquet)?